# Gale Shapely algorithm with restrictions

Tags: algorithm

https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397503003190/1-s2.0-S0304397503003190-main.pdf?_tid=c345eb80-0186-4604-a075-de66b5133315&acdnat=1542454506_cbd77022bb6d77246659f7bd211cbb96

I would like help in knowing how to extend gale shapely algorithm to produce stable matching in case of restrictions e.g one man says that I don't want to end up with this woman under any circumstances. I have been reading up but cannot find an explanation that I can understand. please help

Comment: Can' t setting the weight to -INF solve this problem? Though I learned Gale Shaply algorithm long time ago, but I don't understand why this easy measure doesn't work.

Comment: From what I know, in gate shapely there is an array of preferences for all women and an array of preferences of all men e.g Man1: Woman2, Woman1, Woman3. So how will I incorporate the weight thing

Comment: Yes. So I think just skip the proposing procedure maybe correct. Because if a man really hates a woman. Then whether the woman feel good about the man is of no importance. And there's no chance of the woman cancel the engagement with the man, isn't it?

Comment: And, if the algorithm guarantees each person will have a mate, then you should set the "favor" to -INF, I think...

Comment: And if you think this is wrong, feel free to point out, because I' m still not sure about the correctness.

Comment: Honestly, I cant find a way to prove that your method is correct

Comment: Well, but why this is wrong?

Comment: How would the algorithm stop?

Comment: why can't it stop? The procedure is the same as original algorithm! And in the end, if one's "favor" to his mate is -INF, then of course there's no solution of current situation.

Comment: However, in fact, if you add this situation, the "stable marriage" maybe become a little haze.

Comment: Well, I cannot prove my method right, and I become interested in this problem, I' d like to know if you' ll have any solution later.